# docker permission denied for shell script in mysql image placed at docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: mysql, docker

```
FROM mysql:latest
RUN set -ex && apt-get update \
    && apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl unzip
ADD my.sh  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod -R 777 docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Content of my.sh file are :

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir try1
```

The my.sh file has a command to create a directory and when the entrypoint.sh of the image runs this file, it throws a permission denied error. I have changed the owner of the directory as well.
What could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will be executed by `mysql` account, not by `root`, see [source code](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L346).

You could verify it by change `my.sh` as next:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "start"
pwd
id
mkdir try1
echo "done"
```

Then, the error log will be:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my.sh
start
/
uid=999(mysql) gid=999(mysql) groups=999(mysql)
mkdir: cannot create directory 'try1': Permission denied
```

You could see the user which run current `my.sh` is `mysql`, while you currently want to setup `try1` folder in `/`, surely you won't have permission.